# How do I teach a spell to my pet?

Tags: torchlight-2

I see that my pet has spell slots just like I do. I would like to teach him to heal himself, but I can't figure out how to get him to learn the spell. I tried dragging the spell to one of his spell slots, but that didn't work. I don't want to try right-clicking the spell while it's in my pet's inventory, because it still seems like it would teach it to me.

How can I teach spells to my bet?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To teach your pet a spell, put the spell into your Pet's spell inventory (press P to open the Pet Panel, and then select spells);

[image]

Once the spell is in your pet's inventory, simply right click on it in order to teach it to your pet. The tooltip is still worded as though your character will learn it, but as long as the ability is in your pet's spell window, your pet will learn it.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Put the spell into your pets spell inventory and rightclick it.

[image: Petwindow Screenshot]